# Creating XML from a DOM fragment on IE 7/8

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer, dom

Any pointers on creating XML from the DOM in Javascript on IE 7/8?

I use `document.createDocumentFragment()` and `XMLSerializer().serializeToString()` on FF/Chrome/Safari, but on IE8 `document.createDocumentFragment()` creates a `DispHTMLDocument` object, which doesn't seem to be of any use.

Is there something in IE that I haven't come across or do I have to write something myself to generate XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
fragm = xmlDoc.createDocumentFragment();
```

Comment: Thanks. Could not find this through Google.